# Why does this jQuery script replacing the logo on scroll not work?

Tags: jquery

I downloaded this free bootstrap theme, called "Worthy" and I liked it, but I needed to customize it for my use. I meant to make the logo (an img tag with as id "logo"), fade into another image if you even scrolled the littlest part down. This worked, but it kept "refading" every time I scrolled down.
Here is the jQuery script I made and used:

```
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
     if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
         $("#logo").fadeOut(function() {
             $(this).attr("src", "images/logo2.png").fadeIn();
         });
     } else {
         $("#logo").fadeOut(function() {
             $(this).attr("src", "images/logo.png").fadeIn();
         });
     }
 });
```

Here is the site on Dropbox, if you want to see it: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1z2sz0hnemshboe/AACjQjFaoG92WTAQJkriIn_Ka?dl=0 (the logos are just placeholders, hehe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the listener `scroll` will fire on *every* scroll event. Each time you scroll the page.

In your logic where `scrolltTop() > 0`, you should also check to see if you've already changed the image. You could add a class, uses `.data()`, or check the `src` directly.

## EDIT:

Here's some example code:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

  // Check if the current logo is set
  var isLogo2 = $("#logo").attr("src") === "images/logo2.png";


  if (!isLogo2 && jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0) {

    // Change logo if NOT logo 2 and scrolled
    $("#logo").fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "images/logo2.png").fadeIn();
    });

  } else if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() == 0) {

    // Otherwise, if we're at the top of the page
    $("#logo").fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "images/logo.png").fadeIn();
    });
  }

});
```

Note, The logic on those conditions is untested, but you should be able to do some simple debugging if you encounter problems.

## EDIT 2:

What the heck, lets get a working snippet example:

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

  // Check if the current logo is set
  var isRed = $("body").hasClass("red");
  
  if (!isRed && jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0) {

    // Change logo if NOT red and scrolled
    $("body").addClass("red");
    
    // Add a text to ensure we're not re-applying red
    // on EVERY scroll event
    $("<div class='alert'>CHANGED TO RED!</div>").appendTo('body').fadeOut(500);

  } else if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() === 0) {

    // Otherwise, if we're at the top of the page
    $("body").removeClass("red");
    
    // Add a text to ensure we're not re-applying red
    // on EVERY scroll event
    $("<div class='alert'>REMOVED RED!</div>").appendTo('body').fadeOut(500);

  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 9000px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.alert {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
}
.css {
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
  top: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="css"></div>
```

This snippet isn't working with the `src` attribute on an image, but you should see the logic an be able to apply it to your use case.

Comment: I tried changing it, but thje following code doesn't go back to "images/logo.png" when you scroll back up, I now have:

    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    var logo = $("#logo").attr("src");
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0 && logo == "images/logo.png") {
    $("#logo").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","images/logo2.png").fadeIn();
    });
    } else if (logo == "images/logo.png") { 
    $("#logo").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","images/logo.png").fadeIn();
    });
    }
    });

Comment: @EmielSebastiaanHardy Have a look at the updated answer. I included some code.